# Adding characters as a data labels in Barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, frequency

I’ve a variable named as Hours_taken, and made a frequency distribution, which is Ramit_data, portrayed below.

```
Ramit_data

x     freq
1.1-2    1
2.1-3    4
3.1-4    6
4.1-5    4
5.1-6    2
6.1-7    3
```

I’m now making a Barplot by the Ramit_data which is looking like below

```
barplot(Ramit_data$freq,ylim = c(0,7),col = rainbow(6),main="Hours taken by stores",xlab = "Count")
```

[image]

However I want this data to be showcased along with the frequency as a data labels above/within bars.

Note- Data labels design is not required as I’ve just shown what I wanted, hence any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: How about this `plt <- barplot(...); text(x = plt, y = Ramit_data$freq, label = Ramit_data$x, pos = 3, cex = 0.8, col = "black")`?

Comment: plt <- barplot(Ramit_data$freq,ylim = c(0,8),col=rainbow(6)); text(x = plt, y = Ramit_data$freq, labels  = Ramit_data$x, pos = 3, cex = 0.8, col = rainbow(6))

Comment: Thanks mate, its much appreciated